# Where to find an algorithm for decomposing rational functions into elementary fractions?

Tags: partial-fractions, rational-functions

Specifically I need to decompose $\frac1{(1-x)(1-x^n)^2}$ into $\frac{f(x)}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{g(x)}{1-x^n\vphantom{()^2}}+\frac{h(x)}{(1-x^n)^2}$ where $f(x)$, $g(x)$, $h(x)$ are polynomials.

Surely there must be well known methods to deal with this. Can I avoid taking $f$, $g$, $h$ with indeterminate coefficients and then solve a system of linear equations?

In one of the answers here I found a link to something called Heaviside cover-up method but there only denominators with terms up to degree 2 were dealt with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you want to decompose $\frac{1}{a(x)^3 b(x)^2}$, where $a(x)=1-x$ and $(1-x)b(x)=1-x^n$. But $a(x)^3$ and  $b(x)^2$ are coprime polynomials, i.e. their greatest common divisor is 1. Hence there exist polynomials $f(x),h(x)$ such that $1=f(x) b(x)^2+h_1(x) a(x)^3$. Hence
$$
\frac{1}{a(x)^3 b(x)^2}=\frac{f(x)}{a(x)^3}+\frac{h_1(x)}{b(x)^2}.
$$
Set $h(x):=(1-x)^2 h_1(x)$ and then 
$$
\frac{1}{a(x)^3 b(x)^2}=\frac{f(x)}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{h(x)}{(1-x)^2 b(x)^2}=
\frac{f(x)}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{h(x)}{(1-x^n)^2}.
$$
Set $g(x)=0$.

You can find this in any abstract algebra book, or for example in section 5 of http://www.imsc.res.in/~knr/past/part_frac.pdf

Comment: Nice reference! +1

Comment: Yes I agree it is very useful. Although frankly speaking it is slightly disappointing in that the resulting $h(x)$ becomes intractable in that I cannot really give an explicit expression in terms of indeterminate $n$.

Comment: Another thing that remains unclear to me - there seem to exist various possible partial fraction decompositions, e. g. in `Mathematica` there are commands `Apart` and `ApartSquareFree` and both of them give (equally messy) expressions different (both from each other and from the above), in terms of $\frac{f(x)}{1-x}+\frac{g(x)}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{h(x)}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{k(x)}{1-x^n}+ \frac{l(x)}{(1-x^n)^2}$ and some other elementary fractions which I cannot even understand how they appear...

Comment: What would be really ideal for me is some canonical expression directly depending on, say, residues at the poles, orders of zeros, some finite number of nonzero values, that kind of thing...

Comment: Compute in Mathematica

$PolynomialReduce[(x^n + \dots +x^2 + x + 1)^2, (x - 1)^3, x]$
For example:
$PolynomialReduce[(x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)^2, (x - 1)^3, x]$
you obtain ${{p_1},{p_2}}$.
This means
$(x^n + \dots +x^2 + x + 1)^2=p_1(x-1)^3+p_2$

Then compute $PolynomialReduce[(x - 1)^3, p_2, x]$
you obtain ${{q_1},{q_2}}$, which means
$(x-1)^3=q_1\cdot p_2+q_2$. 
Finally compute  $PolynomialReduce[p_2,q_2, x]$.
You obtain {{r},{c}}, where $c$ is a constant,
 which means $p_2=r\cdot q_2+c$.

Comment: Now 
$$
c=p_2-r\cdot q_2=(x^n + \dots +x^2 + x + 1)^2-p_1(x-1)^3-r((x-1)^3-q_1\cdot p_2)=$$ $$
(x^n + \dots +x^2 + x + 1)^2-p_1(x-1)^3-r(x-1)^3+r\cdot q_1\cdot 
((x^n + \dots +x^2 + x + 1)^2-p_1(x-1)^3).
$$
This means that
$c=t_1 (x^n + \dots +x^2 + x + 1)^2+t_2 (x-1)^3$, with
$t_1=1+r\cdot q_1$ and $t_2=-p_1-r-p_1\cdot r\cdot q_1$.

From this you can determine $h_1$ and $f$. I don't know if you can get a closed formula for the 
coefficients of $f$ and $h_1$, but it must be very laborious. This formula should depend on $n$.

Comment: Yes you seem to be right, there is no reason for a simple answer to exist...

Comment: But the coefficients of  $p_1$ show a certain regularity.

Comment: What I was hoping to obtain were numerators with relatively few terms, but it seems that the one over $(1-x^n)^2$ inevitably should have almost all coefficients nonzero.

Comment: What I still don't understand is to what extent are such decompositions unique.

Comment: Look at Theorem 5.2.2 of  http://www.imsc.res.in/~knr/past/part_frac.pdf  This theorem implies that $f$ and $h$ are unique if $g=0$.